# Как правильно создать Docker-контейнер?

Tags: python, docker

Мне нужно обернуть мой парсер, а именно файл `avito_parser_cli.py` из репозитория https://github.com/denis5417/avito_parser в Docker контейнер.

Я создал `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
ADD avito_parser.py avito_parser_cli.py requirements.txt /
RUN python3 -m venv env
CMD ['source', 'env/bin/activate']
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "avito_parser_cli.py"]
```

Я создаю виртуальное окружение и в него устанавливаю нужные мне зависимости. Я использую `ENTRYPOINT` вместо `CMD`, чтобы принимать аргументы командной строки при запуске.

Затем я собрал образ `sudo docker build -t avito_parser_cli .`

Для тестирования я перешел в другую папку и запустил образ `docker run avito_parser_cli "трактор мтз" -t -m 300000 -s 'date' -a`

Все аргументы распарсились правильно и скрипт выдал то что ожидалось. Но также он должен был записать результат в файл `output.csv`, никаких ошибок он не выдал, но файл я нигде не нашел. При запуске скрипта без Docker скрипт успешно создавал файл и записывал в него.

У меня следующие вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я оформил `Dockerfile` и собрал образ? Принято ли создавать виртуальное окружение внутри образа и в нем устанавливать все зависимости, или нужно делать как-то иначе (например, не создавать окружение, а сразу устанавливать все зависимости)?
2. Куда пропал мой `output.csv`? Как сделать так, чтобы он создавался в той же директории, в которой запускается образ и принято ли так делать?
3. Как обычно распространяются такие образы? Достаточно ли просто оставить `Dockerfile` в репозитории с проектом?

Comment: Ваш output.csv внутри контейнера.

Comment: @Александр и как его оттуда достать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Виртуальное окружение внутри контейнера лишнее. Контейнер сам по себе - изолированное виртуальное окружение. Если ваше приложение - единственное, что работает в контейнере (а идеология Docker склоняет именно к такому варианту), то все неодходимые программы и библиотеки можно устанавливать напрямую.
2. Файлы, созданные программами, работающими внутри контейнера, лежат в виртуальной файловой системе контейнера и пропадут после его остановки. Для того чтобы их вытащить из контейнера и сохранить, нужно примонтировать к вашему контейнеру папку хоста и заставить программу писать в примонтированную папку. Подробно описано в [документации](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), примеры и нюансы для Windows можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine), кратко: `docker run -v /path/on/host/machine:/path/inside/container my-docker-image`.
3. Завивит от того, как сильно вы хотите напрягать пользователей вашего контейнера. Если вы хотите избавить их от необходимости скачивать исходники и собирать образ самостоятельно, вы можете опубликовать ваш образ на Docker Hub или в каком-нибудь альтернативном репозитории (например, JCenter), чтобы ваши пользователи могли запускать контейнер просто через `docker run`.

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ, спасибо огромное.

Comment: Впрочем остался один вопрос, файл output.csv создается в корне контейнера, там же где лежат скрипты и requirements. Получается путь к нему /output.csv. Что мне указать для -v чтобы файл сохранялся в той папке откуда я запускаю образ?

Comment: Лучше всего будет либо положить скрипт не в корень, а в какую-нибудь папку, либо заставить скрипт писать файл в отдельную папку, чтобы в ней был только этот файл. Тогда никаких проблем с пробросом этой папку в хост не будет, и вы гарантированно не засветите ничего лишнего.

Answer (score 0):

2. Достать файлик из контейнера можно так:

`docker cp <container_id>:/file/path/inside/container /file/path/outside/container`

3. Лично я их использовал для Дженкиса и имел опцию либо делать из уже готового сохранённого контейнера в формате tar.gz, либо полностью собирать из докерфайла.