# Сохранение файла в папку откуда запущен образ Docker

Tags: python, linux, docker, macos

Продолжение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/931772/260845) вопроса

Мой Python скрипт создает файл `output.csv`. Я обернул его в Docker контейнер.
Вот мой `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
ADD avito_parser.py avito_parser_cli.py requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "avito_parser_cli.py"]
```

Так я создал образ `sudo docker build -t avito_parser_cli .`

Так я его запускаю `docker run avito_parser_cli 'трактор мтз' -t -m 300000 -s 'date' -a`

Мой файл остается где-то в контейнере, но я хочу чтобы он сохранялся на рабочем столе, где я запускаю образ. Насколько я понимаю файл лежит в корне файловой системы контейнера, но как сделать так чтобы он сохранялся на компьютере я не знаю, догадываюсь что нужно использовать `-v` при запуске.

Файл создается в скрипте так

```
with open('output.csv', "w", newline='') as out_file:
    #запись в файл
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно Вам необходимо использовать опцию '-v' при запуске контейнера:

```
docker run -v <local_path_desktop>:<path_in_docker> avito_parser_cli 'трактор мтз' -t -m 300000 -s 'date' -a
```

Где local_path_desktop - это путь к директории на вашей машине, в вашем случае если вы ходите путь к рабочему столу.

А path_in_docker - это путь, куда смонтируется директория local_path_desktop - внутрь контейнера, к примеру это может быть /opt/ (в корень я бы все-таки не рискнул смонтировать).

Вам тогда лучше явно указать путь к файлу который формирует ваш скрипт к примеру:

```
with open('/opt/output.csv', "w", newline='') as out_file:
#запись в файл
```

И тогда ваш файл появится в директории local_path_desktop на вашей машине. Ну и про права нужно не забывать тут уже в зависимости от ОС. Проверить сможет ли docker контейнер создать файл можно командой:

```
docker run --rm -v <local_path_desktop>:<path_in_docker> avito_parser_cli /bin/bash -c 'touch <path_in_docker>/ttttestttt'
```

**UP**
После уточнений, меняем файл Dockerfile на:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /opt
ADD avito_parser.py avito_parser_cli.py requirements.txt /
RUN python3 -m venv env
CMD ['source', 'env/bin/activate']
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/avito_parser_cli.py"]
```

пересобираем - `sudo docker build -t avito_parser_cli .`

запускаем - `docker run -v <local_path_desktop>:/opt avito_parser_cli 'трактор мтз' -t -m 300000 -s 'date' -a`

результат формируется в local_path_desktop

Comment: Я так понимаю <local_path_desktop> нужно заменить на $(pwd), а <path_in_docker> на /opt, верно? А зачем нужно это /bin/bash -c 'touch <path_in_docker>/ttttestttt'? Почему не mkdir <path_in_docker>?

Comment: Если $(pwd) это директория в которой нужно сохранить файл на машине, а /opt - директория куда пишет скрипт в докере, то - да, так и меняйте. /bin/bash -c 'touch <path_in_docker>/ttttestttt' это просто для проверки сможет ли docker создать файл это можете не запускать.

Comment: а как сделать так что питоновский скрипт был расположен не в корне? Просто docker не позволяет монтировать в корень, а явно указывать тип файла – плохая идея, так как скрипт может запускаться и не через Docker

Comment: @pinguin обновил ответ, надеюсь так у вас все получится